# Parse PHP SDK doesn't return query result

Tags: php, parse-platform

I was able to install the Parse PHP SDK (version 1.1.2) to my project and got through the quick start guide in successfully creating a TestObject. However, when I tried to query the objects, it returns nothing. I'm stuck and don't know where to go from here.

```
use Parse\ParseQuery;

$query = new ParseQuery('TestObject');
$results = $query->find();
foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result->getObjectId() ." - " $result->get("foo") . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way:

```
$myObj= new ParseObject("TestObject");

$myObj->set("objIdd", 1234);
$myObj->set("objName", "My Name");

try {
  $myObj->save();
  echo 'New object created with objectId: ' . $myObj->getObjectId();
} catch (ParseException $ex) { 
  // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
  // error is a ParseException object with an error code and message.
  echo 'Failed to create new object, with error message: ' + $ex->getMessage();
}

//objectId: "XYZABC", objIdd: 1234, objName: "My Name"

$query = new ParseQuery("TestObject");
try {
  $myObj = $query->get("XYZABC");
  // The object was retrieved successfully.
} catch (ParseException $ex) {
  // The object was not retrieved successfully.
  // error is a ParseException with an error code and message.
}
```

Take a look at this [guide](https://parse.com/docs/php_guide).

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.

I looked into the ParseQuery.php file and found that the query was actually working as I was able to output a json array of objects after the _request method but something goes wrong when 
                $obj->_mergeAfterFetchWithSelectedKeys($row, $this->selectedKeys);
 is called.

Comment: Have you seen this Github entry https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseObject.php

Comment: Yes I've looked into it but couldn't find where things starts to go wrong. Instead, I decided to just go with obtaining the json data using the REST API and go from there.